# How to use javascript to increase or decrease the disabled attribute according to whether there is a value in the input box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I hope to cancel the disabled property of btn when there is a value in the input box, and increase disabled when the input box has no value,
but I have encountered a situation, when I delete the value in the input box, why the button still does not increase the disabled?

```js
let inputDOM = document.querySelector('.input');
let BtnDOM = document.querySelector('.btn');

inputDOM.addEventListener('input', function() {
  console.log(inputDOM.value)
  if (inputDOM.value >= 0) {
    BtnDOM.removeAttribute("disabled")
  } else if (inputDOM.value == "") {
    BtnDOM.setAttribute("disabled", "")
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" class="input">
<button class="btn" disabled>Enter</button>
```

Comment: there should be no `else if`, should just be `else`

Comment: But I tried to use else still, when I can no longer delete the value in the input box, let the button increase the disable

https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/QWrrxxg

Comment: Change `inputDOM.value >= 0` to `inputDOM.value > 0`

Comment: wow~ It turns out that I wrote more inputDOM.value >= 0
Thank you very much for your response

Comment: Is the number supposed to be zero and larger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let inputDOM = document.querySelector('.input');
let BtnDOM = document.querySelector('.btn');

inputDOM.addEventListener('input', function() {
  console.log(inputDOM.value)
  if (inputDOM.value.length > 0) {
    BtnDOM.removeAttribute("disabled")
  } else if (inputDOM.value.length <= 0 ) {
    BtnDOM.setAttribute("disabled", "true")
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" class="input">
<button class="btn" disabled>Enter</button>
```

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you for answering my question perfectly, but I am still confused
why my original spelling is invalid?

Can't judge whether there is a value, if there is, cancel disabled. If there is no value, go to else. Cancel disabled. Do you have to use value.length to judge?

Comment: Everything in a input is a string, it dosnt make any sense to compare them, with numbers, input type number will also give you `string` not `number`

Comment: That's it, thank you for letting me learn something new

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @Tyler2P who is stopping you from improving it.